# Closed circle as a metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, circles

If I take the closed unit circle, $C$, can I create a metric space $(C,d)$, where $d$ is the Euclidean-metric?

The reason for asking is that my text book says that all metric spaces are open, so:
(i) Is my example impermissible as a metric space? or
(ii) For points around the edge of the circle, $a$, the open balls $B(a,\delta)$ aren't your typical open balls, but rather the bit of the balls that intersects with $C$?

Comment: Exactly number 2

Comment: Yes, if $(X, \rho)$ is a metric space and if $Y \subset X$, then the restriction of $\rho : X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to domain $Y \times Y$ is a metric on $Y$. This applies, in particular, to the case that $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ with its Euclidean metric $\rho$ and $Y = S^1$ (your $C$), the unit circle.

Comment: When you claim your book says that "all metric spaces are open", you must understand that it means that if you look at a metric space $(Y, d)$, then the subset $Y$ of $Y$ is $d$-open in $Y$ -- but not necessarily in any larger set $X$ having a metric that induced the metric on $Y$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, $(C,d)$ is a metric space. And, yes, for points in $C$, the open balls are intersection of usual open balls (in $\mathbb{R}^2$) with $C$.

Answer (score 5):

Every metric space $X$ is both open and closed in **itself**; note that $\varnothing$ is by definition both closed and open and that $\varnothing = X^{c}$. So $C$ is open in itself but, when considered as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, is closed in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

I assume by a circle you really mean a circle rather than a disk. Let $a \in C$ and $\delta > 0$. Note that $B(a,\delta) := \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \mid |x-a| < \delta \}$ is an open ball that looks like an open disk. The set $\{ x \in C \mid |x-a| < \delta \} = B(a,\delta) \cap C$ is an open ball in $C$ but looks not like a ball.

Comment: An "open ball" in the unit circle will be either an open arc on that circle or else (if the ball's radius is large enough) the entire circle.

Comment: @murray, True. But why mention it here??

Comment: To clarify for the OP'er.

Answer (score 4):

If $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $A\subseteq X$, then $(A,d')$ is a metric space, where $d'$ is just $d$ restricted to $A$; namely, $d':=d|_{A\times A}$. Usually $d$ will be written instead of $d'$, and we'll just understand by context that it's the restriction. Now $A$ is open in the $d'$ metric, regardless whether or not it's open in the $d$ metric.

A different point of view is your (ii). If $x\in A$, then the $d$'-ball centered at $x$ with radius $r>0$ is equal to the intersection of $A$ with the $d$-ball centered at $x$ with radius $r$. In symbols,

$$
B_{d'}(x,r) = A\cap B_d(x,r).
$$
There is a partial converse to this statement as well. If $B_d(x,r)$ is a $d$-ball with $x\in X$, then the intersection $A\cap B_d(x,r)$ is open in the $d'$ metric. Indeed, if
$a \in A\cap B_d(x,r)$, then setting $\delta:=r-d(x,a)$ implies
$B_{d'}(a,\delta)\subseteq A\cap B_d(x,r)$. To see this, suppose $y\in B_{d'}(a,\delta)$. Then $y\in A$ by the fact that $d'$ only acts on pairs in $A$, and $y\in B_{d}(x,r)$ because $d(y,x) \leq d(y,a)+d(a,x) < \delta+d(a,x)=r$.

Answer (score 4):

The entire space of a metric space and the empty set are open and closed.

You can create the metric space $(C,d_C)$ where $d_C$ is the restriction of the Euclidean metric $d_2$ to the points of $C$ .

The open balls of this metric space will be the open balls in the general Euclidean space intersecting $C$.

$(C,d_C)$ is called a subspace of the original space under the topology induced by the metric(in this case by the Euclidean metric $d_2$).

Also a subset $A$ of $C$ is open in $C$ iff exists an open subset $B$ of the general Euclidean space such that $A=B \cap C$.

The same is true a for a subset of $C$ to be closed in $C$.